# No Option to Burn ISO on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, dvd, iso-image, burning, compact-disc

[From what I hear](http://windowsteamblog.com/blogs/windowsexperience/archive/2009/04/13/burn-iso-images-natively-in-windows-7.aspx), Windows 7 is able to burn ISO files natively.  I should be able to right-click on a given ISO and choose "Burn disk image", but I do not have that option on any ISO I try.  I am assuming that I fudged the associations somehow.

Can you help me get back on track?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you don't have that option; my copy of Windows 7 doesn't either. I use Alex Feinman's ISO Recorder tool, it works very well. It adds a "burn" option to the context menu for ISO files. http://isorecorder.alexfeinman.com/W7.htm

Answer (score 3):

Select your file, and press the BURN button at the bottom of the Windows Explorer. (The file browser).

Like this:

[image]

Also, you can try [ImgBurn](http://www.imgburn.com/) . Better in every aspect, free, well supported, bla bla. Ultimate freeware tool for Windows in my opinion. (One of those 'musthaves').

Comment: You can use Alt+Print Screen to get just the active window

Comment: This does not burn the iso to disk.  This burns a cd with an iso file on it.

Comment: @sixtyfootersdude - You sure? I'll try it with a rewritable disc once I get one.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried double clicking the iso file?

Comment: Or if you have the ISO extension associated to a different program, you can choose Open With > Windows Disc Image Burner

Answer (score 1):

Windows 7 has the "Burn Disk Image" when right clicking an ISO file but sometimes another burning program takes over as the windows default program and you lose the option.  The fix is to go to default programs in the control panel and set Windows Disk Image Burner as the default program.  This will put the option back in your right click menu.